# Can't open zip file to read unicode characters

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, zlib

I have a problem to open zip file and read inner text file content as Unicode characters.
so when call this function , the file opens and I can read the inner text file.

```
unzFile uz = unzOpen("<path to file>\\sample.docx");
```

but I need to read inner text file as Unicode file. so when I replace the function call  with this

```
unzFile uz = unzOpen64(L"<path to file>\\sample.docx");
```

the function returns NULL, i.e. file does not opened.

Any ideas about this ?

Comment: Is the library you are using (minizip?) compiled as UNICODE? If it is included as source files then is your program compiled as UNICODE?
Project -> General -> Character Set -> Use Unicode Character Set.

Comment: I've to compile my project and minizp with Unicode character set and UNICODE macro defined, but it's does not solve the issue.

Comment: Can you use debugger to trace it down to the "CreateFile()" call? I.e. just step into this unzOpen64 function and see what is going on until you hit OS call.